# Sorting DOM elements does not work properly on mobile devices(android browser, chrome, safari)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, mobile-browser

I have a div with elements inside that i would like to sort by data value.

```
$('div#mainFrame div.element-container').sort(function(a, b)
{
    return parseInt($(a).data('price')) < parseInt($(b).data('price'));
})
.appendTo('div#mainFrame');
```

I've tried it with chrome/firefox(pc) where it works perfectly fine, however it does not work
with safari nor does it work with the android browser.

[Here is a jsfiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/5PshD/2/)

Comment: Works on Chrome/Android 4.2.

Comment: Okay, its working fine in chrome for both pc/mobile/mac.

Comment: please let me know if you've found a solution for this, as i am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to the problem.

```
$('div#mainFrame div.element-container').sort(function(a, b)
{
    return parseInt($(b).data('price')) - parseInt($(a).data('price'));
})
.appendTo('div#mainFrame');
```

The reason for this is that the sort expects a number, not a boolean return value.